# Google sheet array formula running count

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup, array-formulas, countif

I would like to create an array formula for a running count/index based on certain criteria. I can create the count/index with standard formulas but would like to be able to insert rows without adjusting the formulas everytime

Herewith a link to a sheet that shows the desired result in green for all items that match C in the index column

[Array formula for indexing sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MOCrzrcMwFaTujHbJYXmxNVAW8LoqR0j0kadLrF85iA/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="",, IF("C"=VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), 
 IF(A2:A<>"", {ROW(A2:A), A2:A}), 2, 1), 
 COUNTIFS(A2:A, "C", ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), 0)))
```

[image]